# Diferencias entre ASP.NET Core Web Application y Web Application .Net Framework

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019

Cual es la diferencia entre:

[image: ASP.NET Core Web Application]

y entre:

[image: ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework)]

Osea, he visto que al crear paginas web que es lo que quiero, más usan el .NET Framework y no el .NET Core.

Estoy bien al querer usar a cualquiera de los 2 para crear una pagina web para un trabajo académico?

Deberia usar el Vb 2019 ,2017 o 2015?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En principio, ambos frameworks te van a permitir crear aplicaciones Web, pero existen diferencias significables entre ellos.

Como exponer todas las diferencias entre ASP.NET Framework y ASP.NET Core, sería objeto de un artículo extenso o incluso un tutorial, te comentaré lo importante para entenderlo.

**1 -** La aplicaciones creadas con el framework .NET Core son **multiplataforma**, esto quiere decir que las puedes ejecutar tanto el Windows como en Linux. Las creadas con .NET Framework solo se pueden ejecutar sobre Windows (**IIS**).

**2 -** .NET Framework, es la estructura clásica que viene heredada desde los antiguos ASP.NET Web Forms (librerías **System**), y que ha evolucionado hasta los últimos frameworks como ASP.NET MVC.

**3 -** Por otra parte .NET Core, es un framework **totalmente nuevo** y reescrito desde cero, que pretende dar un enfoque más cercano a los actuales estándares, y al desarrollo de aplicaciones Web (Multiplataforma).

Respecto a tus preguntas:

**- Más usan el Framework y no el Core:**
Es verdad que se usa mas .NET Framework que .NET Core, y es simplemente por que .NET Core es nuevo, y aunque los cambios entre ambos no son significativos a nivel de programación, si lo son a nivel de implantación.

**- Deberia usar el Vb 2019 ,2017 o 2015?:**
Siempre utiliza la última versión de Visual Studio, aunque si vas a desarrollar aplicaciones de .NET Framework como Web Forms o ASP.NET MVC 3 o 4, igual es más conveniente utilizar versiones más antiguas de Visual Studio. En cambio, si optas por .NET Core, siempre utiliza la última versión.